# Why Linux kernel 3.0+ cancels super_operations.read_inode? Request for new references~

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, operating-system, linux-kernel

Before Linux kernel 2.6, super_operations (include/linux/fs.h) have both `read_inode` and `write_inode` functions. But newer kernel does not have `read_inode` any more, then when and how does the VFS read in inode information from specific file system implementation? What is the new course of inode related processing in VFS?

Do you have any updated materials on how to implement file systems under NEW kernel VFS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is practically in the [commit log](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=commitdiff;h=12debc4248a4a7f1873e47cda2cdd7faca80b099).
Edit: See the immediate parent commits of that one for how the practical transformation looks in the file systems.

Comment: Thank you so much. You made me learn a new source of reference that I did not know before. That information is very useful.